# jquery - how to have one select box provide the options for another

Tags: jquery

I have 2 select boxes one which contains counties and the second which contains towns within those counties.

I'm trying to make it so that the first select box dictates the values available in the second and if they have not selected the first set of options, the second is visible but grayed out until a selection has been made.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code speaks for itself:

HTML:

```
<select id="counties">
    <option> </option>
    <option> somerset </option>
    <option> hertfordshire </option>
</select>

<select id="towns" disabled="true">
</select>
```

JS:

```
var countyTowns = [
    ["Bath", "Bristol"],
    ["Letchworth", "Hitchin"]
];

$("#counties").change(function() {
    var county = this.selectedIndex - 1;
    $("#towns").empty();
    if (county === -1) {
        $("#towns").attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
        var towns = countyTowns[county];
        for (var i = 0; i < towns.length; i++) {
            $("#towns").append($("<option></option>").text(towns[i]));
        }
        $("#towns").attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

When ever the counties select box changes grab the selectedIndex and grab the list of towns from your data list. If the selected index is 0 then disabled the towns.

If it's something selected then grab the list of towns from your data and append options to the select.

All you need is actual data for counties & towns. I'm not giving you that

Live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/wS3BZ/2/)